Инициализация массива указателем на char в списке инициализации
class Frabjous
{
private:
  char fab[20];
public:
  Frabjous(const char * s = "C++") : fab(s) { };
  virtual void tell () { std::cout << fab; }
};

VS code выдает ошибку инициализации. Я что-то упускают или это просто опечатка?
P.S Это код из книги Стивена Пратта, раздел повторного использования кода, задание.
Так это выглядит в книге:



Язык программирования С++ 6-е издание Лекции и упражнения(C++ Primer Plus). Глава 14, Вопросы для самоконтроля, вопрос номер 2. стр 798

Во-первых, не давайте код картинкой; во-вторых, или используйте strcpy, или сделайте const char * fab (в этом случае позаботьтесь о существовании строки все время существования объекта).

@Harry Виноват, учту. Это код в книге Пратты в разделе задания. Сам бы я написал что вы советуете, просто меня смутил этот код, не мог понять если Пратта его оставил значит так и должно быть или это просто опечатка.

Очень странно (в смысле у Праты). Что за книга? Ну, чтоб найти и посмотреть контекст. Желательно с указанием раздела (номера). У меня под рукой его "C Primer Plus"? там такого кода не нашел...

Видимо, неспроста её НЕ РЕКОМЕНДУЮТ на enSO.
